# how to remove files in subdirectories folder in python2 with all occurrences of the string

Tags: python-2.7, file, csv

I'm new to python2 & having a challenge in finding all the occurrences of the string in a CSV file.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(search_folder):
    if file_name in files:
        print (os.path.join(root, file_name))
        print ('deleting the file......!!')
        os.remove(os.path.join(root,file_name))
```

This is deleting only the first occurrence and would appreciate your help.!

Comment: Please include some more details to help others reproduce the problem. Can you give an example file tree, an example value of `file_name`, and the expected result? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm trying to find all the occurrences of a list (ex: x, y, z) where the elements are having more than occurences. I want to list all the searches and delete those files which are having the matched string in the file.